# foreach and input type submit in php?

Tags: php, foreach

My problem is the buttons don't work, the only thing that happens is that it reloads the page. And is there anyone that know how to make new buttons instant after I create them in my database?

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" class="index_head" id = "login_form" >
<?php 
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        require "gettops.php";
        $tops = getTops();
        if(!empty($tops))
        foreach ($tops as $top) {

        if(isset($_POST[$top[0]]) && !empty($_POST[$top[0]]))
        {
            header("location:forgot_checkin.php");
        }

        ?>  
            <input type="submit" Name="print" value="<?php echo $top[0]; ?>" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" />

     <?php } //end foreach ?>   

<input type="submit" Name="print" value="Download Excel" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">
<input type="submit" Name="print" value="Download Excel" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">
</form>
```

Comment: Everything is ok, `type="submit"` send form to selected `action` which is current file in your case.

Comment: your code has some issues, first: headers should come first before any output, otherwise PHP can't add them to response header, and second, why you defined multiple submit buttons with similar name and value?

Comment: Can you specify what you're exactly trying to accomplish?

Comment: Im trying to make a top bar with buttons and it should get the link and button name from database. And the two last buttons are just test buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is not submitting anywhere: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is equivalent to `"#"` or `""`. You should include the place the form should submit to and avoid `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Most of these SERVER_VARS are depreciated anyway.

I'm not entirely sure on your question vs. the code that is present for creating new buttons, but you can do:

```
<? foreach ($query as $row) { ?>
    <a href="<? echo $row['link']; ?>"><input type="button" Name="print" value="<?php echo $row['button']; ?>" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" /></a>
<? } ?>
```

You can of course make the button line an echo and never leave php mode. But are there multiple buttons just redirecting? Or do they submit the form to multiple places? If they just link you don't even need a form an can append `<a href="#"></a>` around your button or append `onclick="#"` to the button tag (or nicer: using jQuery('').click({});.

Comment: Final code :
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" class="index_head" id = "login_form" >
<a href="index.php"><input type="button" Name="print" value="Home" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" /></a>
<?php 
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  require "gettops.php";
  $tops = getTops();
  if(!empty($tops))
  foreach ($tops as $top) {

        ?>  
  <a href="<?php echo $top[0]; ?>.php"><input type="button" Name="print" value="<?php echo $top[0]; ?>" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" /></a>
     <?php } //end foreach ?>   
</form> : Thanks all!